# How to fix jQuery / Ajax / Angular error?

Tags: jquery

Since an update to CiviCRM 5.38 on WP 5.7.2 we are facing a lot of strange behaviours especially with Mosaico and one recurrent error is linked to Ajax / jQuery / Angular and get error such as:

`Possibly unhandled rejection: {"error_code":0,"entity":"Mailing","action":"create","is_error":1,"error_message":"Mailing has not been saved, Content maybe out of date, please refresh the page and try again"}`

I've followed this post but can't improve the overall behaviour and also deactivated 'assets caching' but we still stuck. Any Advices?